# Best algorithm / method to determine path length from noisy GPS points

Tags: algorithms, approximation

i am analyzing a series of GPS points (with time stamps) which are noisy meaning have an accuracy of about 15 meter radius (sometime even more), and i need to extrapolate the distance the vehicle has gone via those GPS points, what is a good algorithm / method to solve such issues ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Comment: @D.W. reading it, i struggle to see how i set my parameters there to fit it, is there a reference that walks you through a similar examples ?

Comment: Note that Kalman filters only use information from the past to predict the next sample, which makes them great for real-time noise filtering. If you have the whole trajectory, you have more information. See, for example, https://geometry.stanford.edu/papers/ccgjs-dts-11/ccgjs-dts-11.pdf